# iOS App Planification - How to handle most efficiently GPS + Data Exchange

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, networking, gps

I have in mind an app that have the following requisites:

- Get GPS data (latitude/longitude) (app #1)
- Send that data to same APP on another device (more info later) (app #2)
- Spend as little battery as possible (app #1)

I have been researching over the net (and of course, on stack overflow), the different ways to accomplish that tasks, but i don't know which could be the most efficient. I'm considering these 2:

- Option 1: Settle a socket connection between app #1 - server - app #2, and exchange the data between them as needed.
- Option 2: app #1 would send data to a web service (server) - server would send push notification to app #2 - app #2 would download the needed data through a web service.

On top of it, i have some questions:

- It's possible to stablish a p2p connection between 2 iOS devices on different networks without a server? (no lan here).
- In term's of efficiently and resource management, would be better to take the option 2? It's most efficient to settle a socket connection, or make small http requests?

Remember that the data that is going to be sent over the network (app #1), would be gathered of the GPS (i suppose that gps lonely is going to take a bit amount of battery life (need to do some tests about that though), so i would like to take the option that is more lightweight over battery).

If you know other way or option, would be awesome to know. Also, if you see any problem on that approaches, would be awesome to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you mean with "(i suppose that gps lonely is going to take a big amount of the resources". What kind oif resources? battery? money? time? bytes?

Comment: Hi AlexWien.

I was thinking about battery life, sorry about that. I'm going to edit the main question to clarify that.

Thanks.